# Use of undefined constant OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI

Tags: php, magento, oauth

I'm trying to connnect with Magento 1.7 API, but I'm getting this error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI - assumed 'OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI'
```

This is my code:

```
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();
}
```

I'm following [this guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html)

I tried installing oauth with composer:

```
{
    "require": {
        "lusitanian/oauth": "1.0.*@dev"
    }
}
```

And I added OAuth to php.ini and restarted Apache as the [answer in this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25447/getting-started-with-magento-rest-api)

```
;extension=oauth.so
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I notice that you still have `;extension=oauth.so` commented out - try removing the `;`

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still getting same error

Comment: Interesting... If you access your PHP Info page (if you're not sure, run a file with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it - is there an OAuth section there?

Comment: No, I don't have the Oauth section